# Parsing And Sorting Excel On iOS App

Tags: ios, excel, for-loop, nsarray

Pardon the non-code question, but I need help figuring out a good flow for what I need done.  In my app, I go through and list all the villages within Thailand.  It starts off with the Territories.  I have a separate spreadsheet for each of those.  Inside those, there are columns for regions districts sub-districts and finally, villages.  What I ideally would like is to have several UIPickerViews, in which the first one simply pulls the territories.  Simple enough, I just make an array from the names of the files, which match up with the territories.  I guess what I need, is if there is a good way to view the inside of that file, get all the different choices for the region, and then so on and so forth with the others.  Suggestions?

Comment: are those spreadsheet in .csv (comma separated value) format?

Comment: @reaffer Yes, it is in CSV.  It can be put in normal excel format if needed, though.